# Root user cannot write to libreoffice folder in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: permissions, libreoffice, root

I am new to Ubuntu/Linux. For some reason I cannot write to the following folder `/usr/lib/libreoffice/share` though I am the root user of my system, in order to add a file and customize LibreOffice.

Comment: What command are you running exactly? Add `sudo` before your command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make changes in the directory `/usr/lib/libreoffice/share` you should have `sudo` privileges. Ubuntu doesn't use a root account by default, so you have to use append `sudo` before you run any command that requires root privileges.

For example, if you are trying to edit a file `config/soffice.cfg/modules/sglobal/menubar/menubar.xml` using `nano` you should run:

```
sudo nano /usr/lib/libreoffice/share/config/soffice.cfg/modules/sglobal/menubar/menubar.xml
```

You could also directly edit this file (without the need to use `sudo`) if you log-in as a root user by `sudo su`, but this is highly **not**  a **recommended** way.

Comment: Using the "sudo su" command along with the "cp" command worked like a freaking charm! :D Thanks!

Comment: Try to use the recommended way - i.e `sudo`.